# É possível criar uma superclasse em Java para funções basicas de CRUD utilizando spring framework?

Tags: java, herança, crud, genéricos, spring-data

Ao trabalhar recentemente em um projeto, observei que temos diversas classes com funções básicas de CRUD e que se repetem, suas únicas diferenças, seriam alguns parâmetros, respostas e chamadas de funções em interfaces distintas, minha duvida é se seria possível criar uma superclasse que possua métodos dinâmicos que consiga receber um objeto, e usar a interface correta para salva-lo, apenas estendendo essa superclasse na classe desejada.

Minha duvida é como eu poderia herdar de uma classe métodos genéricos/dinâmicos sem a necessidade de escrever para cada classe seu CRUD.

exemplo:
Classe 1

```
public class ProdutoService{

@Autowired
private ProdutoDAO produtoDAO;

public void salvar(Produto produto){
    produtoDAO.save(produto);
}

public List<Produto> listarTodos(){
    return produtoDAO.findAll();
}

public Produto buscarPorId(String id){
    return produtoDAO.findById(id).orElse(null);
}
}
```

Classe 2

```
public class ClienteService{

@Autowired
private ClienteDAO clienteDAO;

public void salvar(Cliente cliente){
    clienteDAO.save(cliente);
}

public List<Cliente> listarTodos(){
    return clienteDAO.findAll();
}

public Cliente buscarPorId(String id){
    return clienteDAO.findById(id).orElse(null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então André, acredito que o caminho para solução seja o uso de Generics. Talvez, algo mais ou menos assim (O código abaixo é uma referência, uma luz ou apenas uma ideia):

```
public class Box<T> {

      private T t;

      public void add(T t) {
        this.t = t;
      }

      public T get() {
        return t;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
         Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
         Box<String> stringBox = new Box<String>();

         integerBox.add(new Integer(10));
         stringBox.add(new String("Hello World"));

         System.out.printf("Integer Value :%d\n\n", integerBox.get());
         System.out.printf("String Value :%s\n", stringBox.get());
      }
}
```

Veja o seguinte artigo, muito interessante sobre o tema:
[Usando Generics em Java - DevMedia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-generics-em-java/28981)

Espero que isso te ajude!